# Radiobutton must be checked to show checkboxlist

Tags: c#, checkboxlist

My question is, what code do I have to write so that my `radiobutton1` will show me the `checkboxlist1` which is not visible -> `Visible` set on `False`.

I want to show the `checkboxlist` only if `radiobutton1` is checked.

I am using visual c#2012. Hope you can help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use `Checked` property of the `RadioButton` to identify wether RadioButton is checked or not.

From MSDN : [`RadioButton.Checked`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.radiobutton.checked%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> Gets or sets a value indicating whether the control is checked.

Try This:

```
if(radioButton1.Checked)
{
    //Enable checkboxlist
    CheckBoxList1.Visible=true;
}
```

**EDIT :** 
You should handle it in CheckedChanged EVent handler of the `RadioButton`

Try This:

```
private void radioButton1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if(radioButton1.Checked)
    {
        //Enable checkboxlist
        CheckBoxList1.Visible=true;
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**
if you want to disable another radiobutton try this:

```
private void radioButton1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if(radioButton1.Checked)
    {
        //Enable checkboxlist
        CheckBoxList1.Visible=true;

        //Disable RadioButton
        RadioButton2.Visible=false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay I did like you told me, but now when i check the radiobutton on form, the checkboxlist doesn't show up. Blank area there where it should be...

Comment: @user3083561: You should handle it in RadioButton checked event handler .check my edited answer.

Comment: Can i ask one more thing ? 
When i choose one radio button and the checkboxlist shows up i would like to disable the other radiobutton. Is that possible ?

Answer (score 1):

you can do

```
CheckBoxList1.Visible = radioButton1.Checked
```